# How do I mock id = this.route.snapshot.params.id; in angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, angular-activatedroute

I Want to mock this piece of code:
(This is a attribute in my component class)

```typescript
 id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
```

I need it for my `ActivatedRoute` in my test, the error that I get is

> cannot read property of 'route' undefined.

the mocking that I have for this is :

```typescript
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       // The declared components needed to test the UsersComponent.
       declarations: [
         MatchEditComponent, // The 'real' component that we will test
         // RouterLinkStubDirective, // Stubbed component required to instantiate the real component.
        
       ],
       imports: [FormsModule],
       //
       // The constructor of our real component uses dependency injected services
       // Never provide the real service in testcases!
       //
       providers: [
         { provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceSpy },
         { provide: AlertService, useValue: alertServiceSpy },
         { provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy },
         { provide: MatchService, useValue: matchServiceSpy },
         // { provide: StudioService, useValue: studioServiceSpy },
         {
           provide: ActivatedRoute,
           useValue: {
             useValue: {snapshot: {params: {'id': '1'}}}
             
           },
         },
       ],
     }).compileComponents();
 
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MatchEditComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;   });
```

Comment: Just reconfirm the error you are getting ?`Cannot read property ??? of undefined?`

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: this is the error:  An error was thrown in afterAll
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Comment: add `RouterTestingModule` in your `imports` array

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is giving the same error. This is how it looks now: 
 imports: [FormsModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule],

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you nested `useValue` 2 times:

```js
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    // useValue again
    useValue: {snapshot: {params: {'id': '1'}}},
  },
}
```

instead of

```js
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {snapshot: {params: {'id': '1'}}},
}
```